# script to parse template then generate job dsl file

Tags: python, node.js, bash

I'm thinking of using either nodejs, bash or python. I would like to 99% automate the building of our job dsl groovy file. So for now, here is what I'm planning to do. I'll create a template file

```
// example groovy file, not template
job("somejobname") {
  stringParameters('var1', '', '')
  stringParameters('var2', '', '')
  stringParameters('var3', '', '')
  stringParameters('var4', '', '')
  stringParameters('var5', '', '')
  stringParameters('var6', '', '')
}
```

and now for the template which I will use to dynamically build the above. I'll use @@SP@@ just an example

```
// job.template file
job("somejobname") {
  @@SP@@
}
```

In my nodejs, bash or python script, it will read another external file like values.txt or values.json, whatever.

```
// values.txt
SP=['var1','var2','var3','var4','var5','var6']

// or values.json
{ SP: ['var1','var2','var3','var4','var5','var6'] }
```

Once it's read, the values will be used to replace @@SP@@. The script will generate a new file.

Comment: Using sed `sed 's/@@SP@@/my_replacement_string/' input_file > output_file`

Comment: lol, that's not going to work. Output will be different. I don't want to write the whole string again just to use as replacement. I'd rather edit the real file instead

Comment: Use `sed -i.bak 's/.../.../' file` which will make inplace edit and save the old file as `file.bak`

Comment: I don't want to just replace the string. I also want to loop through the values and generate each line dynamically. I don't want to have a source which also contains the almost final string. Like this, I don't want "stringParameters('var1', '', '')" to be in my source file.

Comment: I have an idea now. I've started writing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple template engine like Mustache - or Mistigri (npm install mistigri)

The template could look like:

```
 job("someJobName") {
 {{#SP}}  stringParameter('{{.}}', '', '')
 {{/SP}}}
```

Comment: That's cool! I wrote one from scratch yesterday and it's working great. I'll checkout mustache and Mistigri. Thanks.